# Wordpress Admin Panel Search posts with custom post meta values along with title

Tags: wordpress, search, metadata, custom-post-type, key-value

Hi I'm having a custom post type named **registration** in that on search I'm trying to add custom meta values along with post title.

Below is my code,

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'registration');
      $query->set('meta_query', array(
          array(
            'key' => 'rg_1job_designation',
            'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
          )
        ));
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

But it's not working.

I have a post **title** -> **John** & **Designation** -> **Designer**
On search by **john** can get 1 result, But on search of **Designer** result is empty (This should also fetch one result).

Did anyone know what's wrong in my code ?

Comment: have u found solutions to it? If yes please share, having same prb. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin search everything

http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/

Answer (score 0):

Before the function ends, you need to return the $query.

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'registration');
      $query->set('meta_query', array(
          array(
            'key' => 'rg_1job_designation',
            'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
          )
        ));
    }
  }
  return $query;
}
```

Comment: No, you don't. `pre_get_posts` is an action - it doesn't have to return anything...